# Principle of superposition for linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I have always learned about the superposition principle for systems of the form

$$\dot x = A x + B u,$$
$$ y = Cx.$$

where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are time invariant matrices of appropriate dimensions. The words attached to this property are that if $y_{1}$ is the output corresponding to $u_{1}$ with IC $x(0)=a$, and $y_{2}$ is the output corresponding to $u_{2}$ with the IC $x(0)=b$, then the output corresponding to $u_{1}+u_{2}$ will be $y_{1}+y_{2}$ with the initial conditions $x(0)=a+b$.

This brings me to the following scalar system
$$ \dot x = xu. $$

If u(t) is a known function of time, then I am sure this system is linear, because it satisfies the two properties of linearity. However, if I simulate the system with initial conditions $x(0)=a$ and input $u_{1}$, and initial conditions $x(0)=b$ and input  $u_{2}$, then the sum of their responses does not equal the response I get with input $u_{1}+u_{2}$. I have tried this with a range of initial conditions.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This system is not linear, because you multiply $x$ with $u$, and not with some constant as in your initial example.

Comment: u is a known function of time, the independent variable. It looks like a linear ODE with varying coefficients.

Comment: But you do agree that your specific example does definitely not have the same form as your generic system given by the first equation?

Comment: Yes I do. However, I thought that since the first system obeys homogeneity and scaling, and so does the second system, there must be some form of the superposition principle holding for this system too. Maybe I'm wrong but I don't see why it fails.